# remove duplicated rows between two tables

Tags: mysql

`t1` - colums: `title`, `story`
`t2` - colums: `title`, `story`

some rows are duplicated between the two tables, i.e. `title` and `story` values are the same.

need to delete that rows from `t2` and move the rest of rows from `t2` to `t1`;

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First delete the duplicate records from `t2`:

```
DELETE
FROM t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t2.title = t1.title AND t2.story = t1.story);
```

Finally, insert the unique records from `t2` into `t1`:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (title, story)
SELECT title, story
FROM t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Create temporary table
CREATE TABLE temp_t LIKE t1;

-- Add constraint
ALTER TABLE temp_t ADD UNIQUE(title, story);

-- Copy data
INSERT IGNORE INTO temp_t SELECT * FROM t1;
INSERT IGNORE INTO temp_t SELECT * FROM t2;

-- copy back and drop temp ( if you dont want these constraints on t1 table)
TRUNCATE TABLE t1;
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM temp_t;
DROP TABLE temp_t;

-- rename and drop ( if you want these constraints on t1 table)
RENAME TABLE t1 TO old_t1, temp_t TO t1;
DROP TABLE old_t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the question is tagged mysql and my answer uses linux commandline, vi and a programming language of your choice, but here is the technique to do what you want:

step 1 - sort both tables, t1 and t2 into t1sorted and t2sorted;

step 2 - remove duplicates - once sorted(this step does not work if tables are not sorted, sort direction ascending/descending is not relevant), simply iterate once through each table, comparing current line with previous line, and skip current line if identical with previous line; you can write a simple program to do this in your favorite language such as C; output to t1sorted_dupesremoved and t2sorted_dupesremoved;

step 3 - now you can find which lines from t2sorted_dupesremoved are not present in t1sorted_dupesremoved so that you can add them to t1sorted_dupesremoved  like this: (assuming linux command line - the grep \< shows only the lines in t2 not present in t1 and they are redirected into the output file after > note that this output file will be overwritten if it exists):

```
diff t2sorted_dupesremoved t1sorted_dupesremoved | grep \< > t2lines_not_in_t1
```

step 4 - now you need to use your favorite editor, such as vi, to edit the output file, t2lines_not_in_t1, to remove the < and extra space inserted by diff at the beginning of each line; then you can concatenate it at the end of t1 like this:

step 5 -

```
cat t2lines_not_in_t1 >> t1sorted_dupesremoved
```

note the double >> to add t2 at the end of t1 - very important, a single > will overwrite t1 instead!

step 6 - now you can sort t1sorted_dupesremoved and you're done! you have exactly one instance of each unique line from t1 and t2 in sorted order in one file;